# need help setting up a probability question

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

> A committee of five is to be selected from a group of 12 children. The two youngest cannot both be on the committee. In how many ways can the committee be selected?

I thought this would be ${^{10}\mathrm C_5}\cdot{^2\mathrm C_1}$, but that is not the case. How would I set this up?

Comment: What have you tried? It is a very hard thing to adapt to... but basically MSE wants you to show what you tried to help you better...

Answer (score 1):

$\def\cbinom#1#2{{^{#1}\mathrm C_{#2}}}\cbinom{10}4\cdot\cbinom 21$ counts ways to set up the committee such that *one* from the two (and four from the other ten) are on it .   That is okay but it is not all you want to count.

You want to count ways to set up the committee of five such that *one* or *none* from the two are on it (that is: not both from the two) and the remainder selected from the other ten.

So you must *add* the count of ways to select *none* from the two and five from the remaining ten.

---

Alternatively: count the total ways to select five from twelve, and subtract the ways to select three from ten and both from the two.

Answer (score 1):

There are $\binom{12}{5}$ total combinations.  There are $\binom{10}{3}$ combinations including both youngest.  Final result $\binom{12}{5}-\binom{10}{3}$.

Comment: why would there be 10C3 combinations including both youngest?

Comment: Select both the youngest and three from the other ten to make a committee of five, @pasofdpkapsfd .